# Deploying angular.js yeoman to GitHub pages

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, github-pages, yeoman-generator-angular

I can't deploy to GitHub pages my [yeoman angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) application.
I was using [deploy yeoman](http://yeoman.io/learning/deployment.html) tutorial:

1. Remove the dist directory from the .gitignore file. Yeoman projects ignore it by default.
2. Add the dist directory to your repository: `git add dist && git commit -m "Initial dist subtree commit"`
3. Deploy the subtree to a different branch. Specify a relative path to your dist directory with --prefix: `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`

But my GitHub page still using code from branch master. For example http://derk153.github.io/app/index.html is showing some data, but not `dist` branch `gh-pages`

GH-page: http://derk153.github.io/

My repo: https://github.com/derk153/derk153.github.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to add your Angular application in a new repository in the branch gh-pages.

I recommend you this things:

- Create a new repo.
- Move your code in this repo.
- Add a new branch gh-pages with the dist folder (like Yeoman recommends).
- You can use a grunt package like this: https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-gh-pages

Check my example: I have this repo to add the code for my github.io main page: [My main github.io repo](https://github.com/MarioAraque/MarioAraque.github.io). Then, I create a new repo with new code [here](https://github.com/MarioAraque/pacman/tree/gh-pages). Check the gh-pages branch, the code is available [here](http://marioaraque.github.io/pacman/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Few minutes ago figured out the same :)